# How do web developers on Mac OS handle the Safari browser's inability to clear cache?

Tags: javascript, html, css, macos, safari

I like a lot of Safari's features, but the inability to immediately clear javascript and css files from cache is a real productivity drain.

I've tried all the usual META tags to prevent caching... no luck.

For PHP sites, I've taken to loading JS,CSS files directly into the HTML output, but this can require onerous changes when it comes to releasing.

For HTML files, I often rename these files (just changing the query string doesn't seem to work), and the include statements in HTML, but this is a real chore.

This seems to be a well-reported problem, and I'm wondering how other developers are dealing with it?

Comment: May you describe how you currently clear the cache in other browsers?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm mistaken, you can clear the Safari cache after enabling Developer mode in preferences. It's an item in the new dropdown that appears, or you can use the hotkey `Command + Option + E`

Comment: Yes, with developer tools enabled, cache emptied as well as page force reloaded, JS and CSS (and HTML) are "sticky".  Do you not find this to be the case?

Comment: I haven't, but I'll do some testing and see what I come up with :)